# jQuery set timeout cycle through links

Tags: jquery

I have an `li` with 6 links. Each link triggers the change of an image and fetches content via AJAX to be displayed in elements on the page. Each link has a unique `id`. (e.g. "linkFirstSlide", "linkSecondSlide", etc.)

Is it possible to set a timer of 5 seconds that each iteration triggers the click of the next `li` link?

So say on page load it triggers `$("#linkFirstSlide").click()` then 5 seconds later it triggers `$("#linkSecondSlide").click()` until it gets to the end in which case then proceeds back to the beginning.

I am trying to build a carousel without actually using a carousel plugin as I require a lot of actions to happen on each click.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// When DOM is ready
jQuery(function($){

    // Select our links
    var $links = jQuery("#linkFirstSlide, #linkSecondSlide, ...");
    var iCurrentLink = 0;

    (function clickNextLink(){

      // Click on current link
      $links.eq(iCurrentLink).click();  

      // Prepare for next one in 5 seconds
      iCurrentLink += 1;
      iCurrentLink %= $links.length;
      setTimeout(clickNextLink, 5000);

    })();

});
```

I also wrote a [plugin that makes it easier to write asynchronous loops](http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php) but the jQuery plugin site is currently offline.

Answer (score 0):

just from the top of my head, you can try this:

```
var links = ['#linkFirstSlide', '#linkSecondSlide'];
var max = links.length;
var current = 0;

function slide(){
    var cur = $(links[current]).trigger('click');
    current++;
    if(current>=max)
        current = 0;
}

setInterval(slide,5000);
```